Transfer a working PHP cURL script with refreshing code for Wordpress from a standalone script
I would like to get some Input a my problem I am trying to solve transferring my standalone php function and js script into a working Wordpress format. I am stuck to transfer this into a working format for my Wordpress page and need some input.
I have created a script for a chained API call to 2 different endpoints In php.
Call 1 to Endpoint a) is sending 3 static body params (api key, user id, password etc) to the API and 1 dynamic value, (userIP adress). In response the API POST a orderREF string and a url to a QR code which should be displayed on the screen. In addition to this, the QR code shall be refreshed every 5 secs.
Once the user scans the QR code successfully the Call 2 to Endpoint b) returns customer name and social security number and some other values which are not so relevant atm. For the user the authentication process has been completed and I want to transfer the obtained data into my customer database.
As you will see in my script I created a working prototype of this in a standalone script but need help to transfer it into a working Wordpress (plugin or shortcode) so I can use this function on specific parts of our page.  I would like to send the user to go through this process before signing up on our website in order to fully verify the identity of the user.
The code I created successfully to carry out the 2 chained API calls and to refresh the QR code by javascript. I have just for simplicity hardcoded the credentials for testing, these will be stored in a .env file
<?php
// Handle AJAX requests for the second API call
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['checkStatus'])) {
    $orderRef = $_POST['orderRef'];

    $apiUser = 'aaa';
    $password = ' xxx ';
    $companyApiGuid = 'yyy ';
    $url = 'https://url/endpoint/2';

    $requestData = array(
        'apiUser' => $apiUser,
        'password' => $password,
        'companyApiGuid' => $companyApiGuid,
        'orderRef' => $orderRef
    );

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($requestData));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
    exit;
}

// Initial QR code generation if not a POST request
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
    $apiUser = 'aaa';
    $password = 'xxx';
    $companyApiGuid = 'yyy';
    $url = 'https://url/endpoint1';

    $data = array(
        'apiUser' => $apiUser,
        'password' => $password,
        'companyApiGuid' => $companyApiGuid,
        'endUserIp' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        'getQr' => true
    );

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    if (!$response) {
        die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    $responseData = json_decode($response, true);

    $apiResponse = $responseData['apiCallResponse']['Response'] ?? [];
    $qrImageUrl = $apiResponse['QrImage'] ?? 'No QR code URL available.';
    $orderRef = $apiResponse['OrderRef'] ?? 'No order reference available.';
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>QR Code and Status Check</title>
<script>
var refreshInterval; // Interval for refreshing the QR code

function refreshQRCode(qrImageUrl) {
    var qrImage = document.getElementById('qrImage');
    if (qrImage) {
        qrImage.src = qrImageUrl + '?' + new Date().getTime(); // Appending timestamp to avoid cache issues
    }
}

function checkStatus(orderRef) {
    fetch('index.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: 'checkStatus=true&orderRef=' + orderRef
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data); // For debugging purposes, log the data received from the server

        // Update the logs with detailed status from the second API call
        document.getElementById('detailedLogs').innerHTML = `
            <p>Auth Success: ${data.authResponse && data.authResponse.Success}</p>
            <p>Auth Error Message: ${data.authResponse && data.authResponse.ErrorMessage}</p>
            <p>API Call Success: ${data.apiCallResponse && data.apiCallResponse.Success}</p>
            <p>Status Message: ${data.apiCallResponse && data.apiCallResponse.StatusMessage}</p>
            <p>Order Reference: ${data.apiCallResponse && data.apiCallResponse.Response && data.apiCallResponse.Response.OrderRef}</p>
            <p>Completion Status: ${data.apiCallResponse && data.apiCallResponse.Response && data.apiCallResponse.Response.Status}</p>
            <p>Hint Code: ${data.apiCallResponse && data.apiCallResponse.Response && data.apiCallResponse.Response.HintCode}</p>
        `;

        if (data.apiCallResponse.Response.Status === "complete") {
            clearInterval(refreshInterval); // Stop refreshing the QR code
            var user = data.apiCallResponse.Response.CompletionData.user;
            document.getElementById('qrImageContainer').innerHTML = `
                <p>SUCCESS</p>
                <p>Personal Number: ${user.personalNumber}</p>
                <p>Name: ${user.name}</p>
                <p>Given Name: ${user.givenName}</p>
                <p>Surname: ${user.surname}</p>
            `;
        } else {
            // If conditions are not met, keep polling every 5 seconds
            setTimeout(function() { checkStatus(orderRef); }, 5000);
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        setTimeout(function() { checkStatus(orderRef); }, 5000);
    });
}

window.onload = function() {
    var orderRef = '<?php echo $orderRef; ?>';
    var qrImageUrl = '<?php echo $qrImageUrl; ?>';
    refreshQRCode(qrImageUrl);
    refreshInterval = setInterval(function() { refreshQRCode(qrImageUrl); }, 5000); // Set up the interval to refresh QR code every 5 seconds
    checkStatus(orderRef);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>QR Code</h1>
    <div id="qrImageContainer">
        <?php if (isset($qrImageUrl) && $qrImageUrl !== 'No QR code URL available.') { ?>
            <img id="qrImage" src="<?php echo $qrImageUrl; ?>" alt="QR Code"><br>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <p>QR Code URL not available.</p>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div id="logs"></div>
    <h2>Log Call Endpoint 1</h2>
    <p>Auth Success: <?php echo $responseData['authResponse']['Success'] ?? 'No data'; ?></p>
    <p>Auth Error Message: <?php echo $responseData['authResponse']['ErrorMessage'] ?? 'No error message'; ?></p>
    <p>API Call Success: <?php echo $responseData['apiCallResponse']['Success'] ?? 'No data'; ?></p>
    <p>Status Message: <?php echo $responseData['apiCallResponse']['StatusMessage'] ?? 'No status message'; ?></p>
    <p>Order Reference: <?php echo $orderRef; ?></p>
    <div id="messageContainer"></div>
    <h2>Log Call Endpoint 2</h2>
    <div id="detailedLogs"></div>
</body>
</html>

For getting this functionality into Wordpress I thought about creating a simple plugin and populate the script so Wordpress can process it (also in regards to JS and AJAX functionality)
I created a simple plugin structure with

main plugin-index.php
api-handler.php for the actuals calls.
template.php for the output
and a /js folder where I locate the js script file for refreshing the QR code.
I call all of this with a shortcode function on the actual page and part needed on the page.

plugin-index.php file
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Plugin Name 
Description: Integrates QR code generation and status check verification.
Version: 1.0
Author: me.
*/

function ba_bank_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('ba_bank-ajax', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/bankid-ajax.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_localize_script('bba_bank-ajax', 'bankidAjax', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ba_bank_enqueue_scripts');

include_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'api-handler.php';

function byggauktion_bankid_shortcode() {
    $response = get_initial_qr_code_data();
    $responseData = json_decode($response, true);
    $qrImageUrl = $responseData['apiCallResponse']['Response']['QrImage'] ?? 'No QR code URL available.';
    $orderRef = $responseData['OrderRef'] ?? 'No order reference available.';

    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div id="qrImageContainer">
        <?php if ($qrImageUrl !== 'No QR code URL available.'): ?>
            <img id="qrImage" src="<?php echo esc_url($qrImageUrl); ?>" alt="QR Code"><br>
        <?php else: ?>
            <p>QR code URL not available.</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div id="updateArea">
            <p>Scan the QR code above. Updates will appear here once available.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="orderRef" value="<?php echo esc_attr($orderRef); ?>">
    <?php
    echo ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('ba_bank', 'ba_bank_shortcode');

function ba_bank_handle_ajax() {
    check_status_update();
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_ba_check_status', 'ba_bank_handle_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ba_check_status', 'ba_bank__handle_ajax');

The api-handler.php
<?php
function get_initial_qr_code_data() {
    $data = [
        'apiUser' => 'aaa',
        'password' => 'xxx',
        'companyApiGuid' => 'zzz',
        'endUserIp' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        'getQr' => true
    ];
    return make_bank_api_call('https://url/endpoint1', $data);
}

function check_status_update() {
    $orderRef = isset($_POST['orderRef']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['orderRef']) : '';
    $data = [
        'apiUser' => 'aaa',
        'password' => 'xxx',
        'companyApiGuid' => 'zzz',
        'orderRef' => $orderRef
    ];
    $response = make_bank_api_call('https://url/endpoint2', $data);
    echo $response;
}

function make_bank_api_call($url, $data) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response ? $response : json_encode(['error' => 'No response from API']);
}


template.php file for the html output
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>QR Code and Status Check</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>QR Code</h1>
    <div id="qrImageContainer">
        <?php if (isset($qrImageUrl) && $qrImageUrl !== 'No QR code URL available.') : ?>
            <img id="qrImage" src="<?php echo $qrImageUrl; ?>" alt="QR Code">
        <?php else : ?>
            <p>QR Code URL not available.</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="logs"></div>
    <h2>Log Call Endpoint 1</h2>
    <p>Order Reference: <?php echo isset($orderRef) ? $orderRef : 'No order reference available.'; ?></p>

    <p>Auth Success: <?php echo $responseData['authResponse']['Success'] ?? 'No data'; ?></p>
    <p>Auth Error Message: <?php echo $responseData['authResponse']['ErrorMessage'] ?? 'No error message'; ?></p>
    <p>API Call Success: <?php echo $responseData['apiCallResponse']['Success'] ?? 'No data'; ?></p>
    <p>Status Message: <?php echo $responseData['apiCallResponse']['StatusMessage'] ?? 'No status message'; ?></p>
    <p>Order Reference: <?php echo $orderRef; ?></p>
    <div id="messageContainer"></div>
    <h2>Log Call Endpoint 2</h2>
    <div id="detailedLogs"></div>
    <script src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/bankid-ajax.js'; ?>"></script>
</body>
</html>


Finally the bankid-ajax,js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var qrImage = document.getElementById('qrImage');
    var orderRef = document.getElementById('orderRef').value;
    var updateArea = document.getElementById('updateArea');

    function checkStatus(orderRef) {
        fetch(bankidAjax.ajaxurl, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            body: 'action=byggauktion_check_status&orderRef=' + encodeURIComponent(orderRef)
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            // Dynamically update content
            if (data.status === 'complete') {
                updateArea.innerHTML = '<p>Verification completed successfully for user ' + data.user.name + '</p>';
            } else {
                updateArea.innerHTML = '<p>Status: ' + data.status + '</p>';
            }
            if (data.newQrImage) {
                qrImage.src = data.newQrImage + '?refresh=' + new Date().getTime();
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            updateArea.innerHTML = '<p>Error checking status. Please try again.</p>';
        });
    }

    setInterval(() => checkStatus(orderRef), 5000);
});

I am not able to connect to the API on this way and the QR cant be displayed. I have tried to simplify it more. Could try to give me an advice how to streamline my script more for my Wordpress use-case?
Thank you

"I am not able to connect to the API" - are you getting an error in your console?

You've probably got this on your radar, but you have a setInterval that you'll probably want to clear on success.

It's unclear specifically what "not able to" actually means in practical terms. Please explain the problem more clearly and specifically. We cannot fix ambiguous problems. See also how to make a [mre] of your issue. Thanks

It doesn't look as though you're verifying your AJAX call  from the script. When you localize your script you should also pass a nonce value across to the JS, then add that nonce as a security check in your AJAX call, then, before executing the PHP, verify the nonce.  You're also not calling the right action: byggauktion_check_status but you don't have a function with that name, you have check_status_update

To expand on my comment, you're missing a couple of key things in your code.
First, lets generate a nonce and pass it across to your JS.
function ba_bank_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('ba_bank-ajax', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/bankid-ajax.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    $bankcheck_nonce   = wp_create_nonce( 'bankcheck_nonce' );
    wp_localize_script( 'bba_bank-ajax', 'bankidAjax',
        array(
            'ajaxurl'           => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'bankcheck_nonce'   => $bankcheck_nonce
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ba_bank_enqueue_scripts' );

Now, in your JS file you'll want to call that alongside the ajaxurl...
//add the nonce value to a variable & add it to your action string
var security = bankidAjax.bankcheck_nonce;
function checkStatus( orderRef ) {
    fetch( bankidAjax.ajaxurl {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: 'action=byggauktion_check_status&security='+security+'&orderRef=' + encodeURIComponent(orderRef)
    } )

Now we have to make sure that your callback function matches the action name you used in your JS and also check your AJAX referer:
function check_status_update() {
    //this checks the ajax referer to make sure it's permitted
    check_ajax_referer( 'bankcheck_nonce', 'security' );
    $orderRef = isset($_POST['orderRef']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['orderRef']) : '';
    $data = [
        'apiUser' => 'aaa',
        'password' => 'xxx',
        'companyApiGuid' => 'zzz',
        'orderRef' => $orderRef
    ];
    $response = make_bank_api_call( 'https://url/endpoint2', $data );
    echo $response;
    //stops AJAX from returning a 0 as a response, basically ends the process for you
    wp_die();
}
//this next bit is key, you have to add an action and use the action name from your JS
//in your JS you used byggauktion_check_status
//for logged in users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_byggauktion_check_status',  'check_status_update' );
//for logged out users, if this needs to function on the front end
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_byggauktion_check_status',  'check_status_update' );

Obviously this is untested, but with those added elements you should be able to debug the rest yourself.  :-)  Best of luck.

thanks a Bunch @Tony Djukic, with this I already came a lot further.

Tahnk you sir! Yeah, the connection to the 1 endpoint is going smoothly and the QR code is displayed and I can prompt the OrderRef on the Html. Im currently a bit stuck in refreshing the img.

Glad to hear... ...let me take a look at the next piece.

To elaborate on my answer in the comment, I incorporated the JS now int the main file. I am still not really coming to the right solution that the img is refreshing. Any suggestings from you on this function below?
function byggauktion_bankid_enqueue_scripts() {
wp_register_script('byggauktion-bankid-ajax', ''); 
$bankcheck_nonce   = wp_create_nonce( 'bankcheck_nonce' );
wp_localize_script( 'byggauktion-bankid-ajax', 'bankidAjax',
    array(
        'ajaxurl'           => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'bankcheck_nonce'   => $bankcheck_nonce
    )
);

$js_code = <<<JS
setInterval(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: bankidAjax.ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'byggauktion_check_status',
            security: bankidAjax.bankcheck_nonce,
            OrderRef: jQuery('#OrderRef').val()
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.Success) {
                jQuery('#messageContainer').html('<p>API Call Success: ' + response.Success + '</p><p>Status Message: ' + response.StatusMessage + '</p>');
            } else {
                jQuery('#messageContainer').html('<p>API Call Success: ' + response.Success + '</p><p>Status Message: ' + response.StatusMessage + '</p>');
            }
        },  
        
            error: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            jQuery('#messageContainer').html('<p>API Call Error: ' + response + '</p>');
        }

    });
}, 5000);
JS;

wp_add_inline_script('byggauktion-bankid-ajax', $js_code, 'after');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'byggauktion_bankid_enqueue_scripts');

You shouldn't put the script in the function, have it separate.  Not sure where it's supposed to get the image from though.  I'm confused by your snippet above.  It doesn't make sense the way you have it structured.  The JS should be in a separate file and you should be sending across the image from PHP callback to the AJAX, then loading it into a container  using JS when you receive the resposne.
